# Sublime Text: Adding dot as word separator?

Tags: sublimetext2

Its really annoying when Sublime Text selects the entire word in Javascript which is actually delimitated by "dots". How to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

In Preferences.sublime-settings, change "word_separators" to the following line

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?\\.",
```

Notice that I added "\\." in the end of the word_separators strings.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: When I put this in a `.sublime-settings` file of a plugin, will it work for the scope of the plugin only or do I need to take extra steps?

Comment: I have no idea, you need to test that.

Comment: I don't think `word_separators` uses regex, and the `.` is already in there as the first character.

Comment: I read it somewhere and I added that and it worked. I assume `\\.` and `.` are different here. As I can see another `.` in between somewhere near comma and semi-colon.

Comment: Settting user not Default will work. (delete all the dot in the word_separators)